# How to pass a boolean from javascript to python?

Tags: javascript, python

The following seems to pass a string instead of a boolean value. How would I pass a boolean?

```javascript
$.post('/ajax/warning_message/', {'active': false}, function() {
            return
       });
```

```python
def warning_message(request):
    active  = request.POST.get('active')
    print active
    return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In your Python code do this:

```
active = True if request.POST.get('active') == 'true' else False
```

Or even simpler:

```
active = request.POST.get('active') == 'true'
```

Be aware that the `get()` function will always return a string, so you need to convert it according to the actual type that you need.

Comment: I would suggest the following for ease of reading

`active = request.POST.get('active', False) == 'true'`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you could send boolean value to the server as `true/false` or `1/0`, on the server-side you can check both cases with `in`:

```
def warning_message(request):
    active = request.POST.get('active') in ['true', '1']
    print active
    return HttpResponse()
```

---

Otherwise, if you are sure that your boolean will be only `true/false` use:

```
def warning_message(request):
    active = request.POST.get('active') == 'true'
    print active
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: An argument could be made that you should just pick either "true" or "1" and only accept that one value, but this is a good solution if you want both.

Comment: @BrendanLong Yes, that's my thoughts as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Oscar is a 1-liner and I'd like to take nothing from it but, comparing strings is not the cleanest way to do this.

I like to use the [simplejson](http://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. 
Specifically [loads](http://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simplejson.loads) parses the natural json form of JavaScript to native Python types. So this technique can be used for a wider set of cases.

This will give you **uniform code techniques** which are easier to **read, understand & maintain**.

From the docs:

> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object.

```
import simplejson as sjson
valid_python_var = sjson.loads(json_str_to_parse)
```

Or in the likely scenario that you are receiving it via parameter passing:

```
var_to_parse = request.POST.get('name_of_url_variable') #get url param
    if var_to_parse is not None: #check if param was passed, not required
        parsed_var = sjson.loads(var_to_parse) # loads does the work
```

Note: Import libraries using common sense, if you are going to use them once there is no need for it.