# How to parse boolean with PyScript from HTML to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, webassembly, pyscript

From a PyScript app, I am providing two radio buttons in my `index.html`,
allowing a user to decide wether synthesis of isotropic gaussian blobs should be overlapping or not (effectively by toggling the value of `Scikit-Learn`'s `cluster_std` value for the `make_blobs` method).

app reference:
https://24ec0d6b-0b55-49be-aeb7-a0046c41abf4.pyscriptapps.com/ea775901-75b9-406d-beac-944d26301b09/latest/

I am currently unable to parse the choice into Python booleans (`True` or `False`)
and always receive a `True` value regardless of which radio button that was clicked.

Experimented a bit with defining the values in `HTML` as double-, single-, or un-quoted as well as switching between different casings (titled, upper, lower) without luck.
Also had a look at other examples/questions here on SO, e.g. [How to pass a boolean from javascript to python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693630/how-to-pass-a-boolean-from-javascript-to-python)

Snippet from the relevant section in the HTML:

```
<div id="input" style="margin: 20px;">
  Should the clusters overlap: <br/>
  <input py-click="generate_blobs()" type="radio" id="true" name="overlaps" value="true">
  <label for="true"> True</label>
  <input py-click="generate_blobs()" type="radio" id="false" name="overlaps" value="false">
  <label for="false"> False</label>
</div>
```

And similarly for the Python snippet:

```
def generate_blobs():
    """Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering"""

    over_laps = js.document.getElementsByName("overlaps")
    for element in over_laps:
        if element.checked:
            overlap = bool(element.value)

            print(overlap, type(overlap))
            
            break
    paragraph = Element("Overlap")
    paragraph.write(f"overlaps: {overlap}")

    n_samples = 4_000  # if overlap else 2_000
    cluster_std = 1.5 if overlap else .4

    X, y = datasets.make_blobs(
            n_samples = n_samples,
            n_features = 2,
            centers = 5,
            cluster_std = cluster_std,
            shuffle = True,
        )

    return X, y
```

Result from setting the False option:

[image: radio button choice: false]

Any suggestions are most welcome as I am running out of ideas to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by using `py-click`.

`py-click` is not able to pass the click-event from Javascript.

---

Consider using `addEventListener` to the result of `js.document.querySelectorAll`, this way you'll get the event which you can use to get the value

Don't forget to wrap your function in `create_proxy` to ensure it's removed when needed.

---

Small example:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 45px !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input" style="margin: 20px;">
            Should the clusters overlap: <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="true" name="overlaps" value="true">
            <label for="true"> True</label>
            <input type="radio" id="false" name="overlaps" value="false">
            <label for="false"> False</label>
        </div>
        <py-script>
            from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy

            def onInputClick(e):
                elementId = e.target.id
                elementValue = e.target.value

                print(f"Clicked on <{elementId}>, new value: <{elementValue}>")

            for i in js.document.querySelectorAll('input'):
                i.addEventListener("click", create_proxy(onInputClick))
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @0stone0 for the fast answering. I have added your suggestion, and now the result changes from True to False, in the displayed value. Doesn't affect the graph yet for some reason, did I perhaps miss some detail? (wasn't sure where to add the `.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 45px !important; })`. (Upvoted your answer)

Comment: The css included is just to format the stackoverflow snippet. You won't need that. Not sure why your graph is not effected. If you could include an [mre] to your question it would be easier to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying wrt the CSS. I have updated the app with your suggestion: https://24ec0d6b-0b55-49be-aeb7-a0046c41abf4.pyscriptapps.com/ea775901-75b9-406d-beac-944d26301b09/latest/   yet something still hinders the graph from taking selected effect wrt the overlap choice..

Comment: This is a good answer. One further thing you could use - the Pyodide ffi includes some functionality that handles proxy wrapping for the user, as well as tracking proxies that have been assigned, as `from pyodide.ffi.wrappers import add_event_listener`. So you can do `for i in js.document.querySelectorAll('input'): add_event_listener(i, "click", onInputClick)`